# How to turn off automatic updating of fields in the Microsoft Word?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have a simple vsto addin for word which allows me to select one or more pictures from disk then it inserts them into the current document. It works just fine and I have no problems with it. However, each time it inserts a picture word updates all fields in the document. Once the document has a hundred or so pictures this gets pretty time consuming. I need to turn off the auto updating of fields while these pictures are being inserted, then turn it back on when done.
What I have tried is this:
Adding this line at program start,

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Fields.Locked = True
```

Adding these lines at program end,

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Fields.Locked = False
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update()
```

but word still updates ALL the fields in the document with each picture insertion. Is there some other method to accomplish this?
Thanks

Edit: this is the code that inserts the images

```
Sub ImportPictures()

        Dim strPics As String = String.Empty
        Dim arrPics() As String
        Dim i As Long
        Dim vrtSelectedItem As Object = Nothing
        Dim tek As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape = Nothing
        Dim picName As String = String.Empty

        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Fields.Locked = True

        'Open up a file browser so user can choose the spreadsheet for the part
        Try
            Using OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
                OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\"
                OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Images (*.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp)|*.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp"
                OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
                OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
                OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True

                If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                    For Each vrtSelectedItem In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
                        strPics = strPics & "|" & vrtSelectedItem
                    Next vrtSelectedItem

                    strPics = Mid(strPics, 2)
                    arrPics = Split(strPics, "|")
                    System.Array.Sort(arrPics)

                    For i = 0 To UBound(arrPics)
                        picName = Right(arrPics(i), Len(arrPics(i)) - InStrRev(arrPics(i), "\"))
                        tek.LockAspectRatio = True
                        tek.ScaleHeight = 32.3
                        tek.Select()
                        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Format.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
                        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.InsertCaption(Label:="Figure", Title:=": " & picName, Position:=word.WdCaptionPosition.wdCaptionPositionBelow)
                        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Collapse(word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
                        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.TypeParagraph()
                    Next i
                Else
                    MsgBox("User pressed Cancel.")
                End If
            End Using
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Fields.Locked = False
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.SystemModal, "Error")
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: AFAIK automatic updating upon insertion of a pciture is not standard. I suggest editing your question to include the code used to insert the pictures.

Comment: What sort of fields are you referring to? Do you know how to turn off automatic updating on fields normally in Word? If so, record a macro doing it and see the code it produces to get an idea.

Comment: the status bar in word just says "updating the fields in the document" I do not know how to turn this off via word's menu

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/word/microsoft-word-turn-off-field-updating/m-p/3693916/highlight/false#M5440  
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 1):

ActiveDocument.Fields.Locked can only affect fields that exist in the document when that code line is executed. Unless you loop through all story ranges, it will also only affect fields in the document body. If you add another field whose property is 'hot' (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/which-fields-are-updated-when-you-open-repaginate-or-print-document-e9580e16-7239-5263-83a4-061a27210076), it will update as soon as you insert it. Running ActiveDocument.Fields.Locked again will only prevent further updates.